# Changing values ​in two models using one form - did not work. Django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to make changes in two models at the same time. So, according to one topic on the forum, I created two forms in one view and added it to one  html.

I think I am doing something wrong in my second form. Why my value in my model  does not change to False?

It looks more or less like that.

**views.pl**

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'btn_massage_order' in request.POST:
        ordering_form = OrderingMassageForm(data=request.POST)
        if ordering_form.is_valid():
            ordering = ordering_form.save(commit=False)
            massage_product = query_product # nazwa produkty
            masseurs = query_user # massage
            massage_time_interval = time # time example 60 min
            price_massage = price # price
            day_week = clean_my_date # day week
            time_compartment = ordering_form.cleaned_data['time']
            [...]
            ordering.massage_product = massage_product
            ordering.masseurs = masseurs
            ordering.massage_time_interval = massage_time_interval
            ordering.time_compartment = time_compartment
            ordering.price = price_massage
            ordering.day_week = day_week
            [...]
             ordering.save()
    else:
        ordering_form = OrderingMassageForm()

    #next form i views
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'btn_massage_order' in request.POST:
        ordering_form = OrderingMassageForm(data=request.POST)
        ordering_form_on_off = TimeOnTimeOff(data=request.POST)
        if ordering_form_on_off.is_valid() and ordering_form.is_valid():
            ordering_form_on_off = ordering_form_on_off.save(commit=False)
            # the value that will be save
            reservation = False
            # I receive my object
            time_compartment = ordering_form.cleaned_data['time']
            # assigning my object
            ordering_form_on_off.time_compartment = reservation
            #save
            ordering_form_on_off.save()
    else:
        ordering_form_on_off = TimeOnTimeOff()
```

**forms.py**

```
class OrderingMassageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderingMassage
        fields = ('time',
                  'place',
                  'payment_method',
                  'name',
                  'surname',
                  [...]


class TimeOnTimeOff(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('free_or_no',
                  )
        widgets = {
            'free_or_no': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
```

**models.py** 
(in which I try to change the value through a second form that does not work)

```
class Time(models.Model):
    day_time = models.ForeignKey(DayTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    compartment = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    free_or_no = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    time_equivalent = models.IntegerField()
```

**template**

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ ordering_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="btn_massage_order" class="btn btn-primary">Potwierdż rezerwacje</button>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing here. What's the point of a form whose only field is a hidden input?

Comment: I want to change the field in the 'Time' table after sending the first form (which edits the OrderingMassage table). Maybe I can do it in a different way without creating a new form. If so, how can I do it too?

Comment: You don't make 2 separate if statements for the request.POST. Handle both forms in the same if statement.